# Is double 0.0 is greater or less than 0 in java

Tags: java, double

I would like to ask for more clarification. Here my sample program

```
double diff = 7.500 - 7.500;
System.out.println(diff); // result 0.0
if (diff > 0) {
    System.out.println("+" + diff ); //result +0.0
} else {
    System.out.println("-" + diff ); //result -0.0
}
```

My result is **-0.0**. My expectation is 0 == 0.0 then skip if else condition. But it enter to the else condition.Is double 0.0 is greater or less than 0?

Comment: The `else` clause will be executed if `diff` is not greater than zero.  This includes the case where `diff` equals zero.

Comment: @OP: I don't think you understand how `else` works :(  And yet, you still got upvotes. Go figure...

Comment: @sstan actually I don't want equal case. But seems else includes  equals zero condition.

Comment: Of course it does... How would the `else` know that you want to exclude certain conditions? That's not how `else` works.

Comment: Hi all , Thanks for answering. But  I think @msandiford comment is correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my answer:

```
double diff = 7.500 - 7.500;
    System.out.println(diff);

    if(diff>0){
        System.out.println("+"+diff);
    }else if(diff<0){
        System.out.println("-"+diff);
    }else if(diff==0){
        System.out.println("="+diff);
    }
}
```

and my result is this :
0.0
=0.0

you must forget that the 0.0 equal 0 is 'else the 0.0 > 0' other the '0.0 >= 0'

Answer (score 10):

Note that you are checking if diff > 0 - so if it IS zero, you are printing -0.0

Answer (score 4):

In your case, you compare 0.0 to 0 using (greater) `>` so 0.0 is not strictly greater than 0, (it is equal). Then your programme go to the `else` section.

```
if(diff == 0 ) {
    System.out.println("+" + diff ); //result 0.0
} else if (diff > 0) {
    System.out.println("+" + diff ); //result +diff
} else { // diff is less than 0 
    System.out.println("-" + diff ); //result -diff
}
```